# [SpringCloudGateway-WebFlux]: How to call non-blocking WebClient API in synchronized block in reactive paradigm to ensure its invoked only once

Tags: spring-webflux, spring-cloud, project-reactor, spring-cloud-gateway, spring-webclient

We are migrating our API Gateway application from Netflix Zuul library to Spring Cloud Gateway framework.
We are migrating one of the custom global pre-filter which deals with retrieving auth token from another microservice/API. This auth token has expiry time associated with it. The token in refreshed once it gets expired or idle beyond its limited duration.
The existing code is written in imperative style using synchronized block as follows so that the retrieved auth token is cached locally and third party is invoked only one time for a valid auth token:

```
class AuthTokenManager {
    private volatile String authToken;

    private final Connector connector;
   
    public AuthTokenManager(final Connector connector) {
        this.connector = connector;
    }

    public String getAuthToken() {
       if (StringUtils.isBlank(authToken) || isAuthTokenExpired()) {
           fetchAuthTokenFromApi();
       }
       return this.authToken;
    }

    public void fetchAuthTokenFromApi() {
        final String oldAuthToken = this.authToken;
        if(oldAuthToken.equals(this.authToken)) {
           synchronized (this) {
               if(oldAuthToken.equals(this.authToken)) {
                   this.authToken = this.connector.generateAuthToken(userName, password);
               }        
           }
        }
    }

    private boolean isAuthTokenExpired() {
        return isExpired() || isIdle();
    }

    private boolean isExpired() {
       // token age exceeded expiry timeout
    }

    private boolean isIdle() {
       // token access time from now has exceeded idle timeout
    }
}
```

We tried to migrate above code in reactive paradigm using synchronized block as follows:

```
    public Mono<String> fetchAuthTokenFromApi() {
         final String oldAuthToken = this.authToken;
         if(oldAuthToken.equals(this.authToken)) {
           synchronized (this) {
               if(oldAuthToken.equals(this.authToken)) {
                   this.connector.generateAuthToken(username, password)
                     .map(token ->  {
                         this.authToken = token;
                         return this.authToken;
                   }).cache(Duration.ofSeconds(expiryTimeout));
               }
         }
         return Mono.create(consumer -> consumer.success(this.authToken));
    }
```

Above code works fine in case of single request/thread, however in case of concurrent threads, each request is calling third party API to retrieve authToken and does not uses cached authToken.

I have read multiple articles on this issue and found that most of the suggestion is around using Mono.cache() to cache the token. I tried with that also however still the issue occurs in case of concurrent requests.

How can we write synchronized critical section mutuable code in reactive paradigm so that third party API is invoked only once and result is cached and other requests uses cached token?
Any lead will be of great help.

Comment: I'm still going to suggest `Mono.cache(Duration)`, as it is the best fit for caching a single value with a timeout. Can you show us your Mono.cache() attempt?

Comment: @PatrickHooijer thanks a lot for suggestion.. I have updated above the usage for cache(). Issue occurs when multiple requests come at the same time. Each request thread will hold reference to generateAuthToken Mono publisher. On subscription, each thread will execute third party API to generate Auth token and update cache multiple times. Expected behaviour is third party must be invoked only once at a time for any number of requests. One request should get token and update in cache and rest must use token from cache instead of calling third party API.